Vim search makes all text highlighted
I typed the following command /\/* in Vim trying to search for /* in the file, however now all the text within the file is highlighted and I can't get rid of it.
How do I undo what I have done and what's the correct way to search for the keyword I meant to search for?
I tried to search for another keyword and the highlights are gone. Can someone explain what my original command did? Why did it highlight the whole text?

What happens is this: \/ would match the first / after the cursor all right, but every character in your buffer also matches the pattern and is therefore highlighted.
In Vim, search is done with regular expression patterns, which are made of so-called atoms.
In your pattern, \/*…

\/ is a first atom: an escaped /. A straight / would make your pattern very ambiguous because Vim uses / as a separator between the pattern and an optional offset. / is a special character that must be escaped if you want to use it literally in your pattern.
* is understood as a greedy quantifier. It tells Vim to match "zero or more, as many as possible" of the preceding atom. * is another special character that must be escaped to be used literally.

Knowing which character is special and which is not is key to using regular expressions properly.
A more correct pattern would be:
/\/\*

with an escaped / and an escaped * because the two characters you want to match happen to be special characters.
See :help magic for possible ways to reduce the need for escaping those characters.
And see Vim clear last search highlighting for getting rid of the highlighting.
